# Google Analytics (or Tag Manager) stuck in debug mode

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using GTM with Google Analytics and I can't get out of debug mode.  I am not in GTM "Preview" mode and don't have the GA debugger extension installed.  It's happening on all browsers - for everybody.  Every page load dumps dozens and dozens of lines in the console like this:

[image]

I have checked all the settings I can think of both on GA and GTM.  All the tags on GTM that use analytics have the debug set to false, and debugging by default is not checked for the environment (screenshots).

I am kind of frustrated and also concerned that this is slowing site browsing.
Any help appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Follow-up - I already suspected this, but it appears that GTM is the culprit.  It's loading analytics_debug.js instead of analytics.js (despite there being no obvious setting set to debug).

[image]

I have another site that uses analytics directly (not through GTM), and it does not have this problem.

Comment: Did you try to clear your browser's cache?

Comment: Yeah.  But also, debug output is showing for everybody, not just on my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out I *did* have a tag that had "use debug version" set to "true".  I *thought* I had checked all the tags, but I hadn't noticed that there is now a 2nd page.